# Serving Advertisements - What should the View be responsible for?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, advertisement-server

My requirements are that Ads have a definite size, could be different media types (although I'd like to focus on Images first) and need to have their impressions tracked

I'm using Spring-MVC and will likely have a service that will retrieve all the relevant ad information

```
adService.getAdsForPage("news");
adService.getFeaturedAd("news");
```

and so on...

My question is, what will my view be responsible for?  I need to track impressions, and I can only really think of how to do that on the server side.  But what would my view look like.

I'd like any example code, ideas, or a link to a page that has some in depth discussion of this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view has just to *display* the ad.

```
<img src="${adService.imageUrl}" />
```

All the business stuff can be handled in `adService`. You can for example add a counter to the `getImageUrl()` method.